# Google Maps v3 fitBounds() bounds,padding:number not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to understand what the padding option for the fitBounds() method does exactly.

```
map.fitBounds(bounds, 100);
```

The option of 100 is said to add padding (at least that's how I read it) according to the docs here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

but I've added various numbers and seem to get nothing (on my use project) unless it is in 100 increments, which is just too much. 
I setup a JS fiddle to show what the capabilities of the padding options are here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/sc9bc4ab/

They seem to be different per implementation, but they have the same issues of 'jumping' once you hit a certain number value.

My question is What does the padding option actually do? It seems very inconsistent. if it's 10 or 20 or 30 on the fiddle it seems to stay the same, when you hit 40 things jump. I've also tried `{padding:50}` or `{padding:[50,50]}` just not a lot of information on this particular issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google Maps API implement a system of discreet zoom levels (click the zoom in/zoom out buttons and notice that the map jumps by a fairly significant amount).

There are two approaches that the API could use to ensure that a particular bounding box is displayed within the Map:

1. Resize the Map element - this may mess with the layout of your page, so is a poor option.
2. Center the map on the bounds, and then select a zoom level that 'best' fits that bounding box within the size of the Map element. **This** is what the API does.

The effect you are seeing, in which the map jumps when you use a padding of 40, is because that is the smallest amount of padding that will cause the zoom level to change by a full integer value. Since the API does not support fractional zoom, anything less than this amount will not cause the appearance of the map to change.

Comment: So the focus on padding here really only affects a zoom level. Seems a bit useless to have that as an option since you would never really know what is the proper padding amount to affect zoom. Then again you could just guess until the 'best' display is appropriate relative to zoom. Thanks for the great explanation!